# Learning Haskell: thunks returned by repeat

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell and wrote this function:

```
continueWith :: [a] -> a -> [a]
continueWith [] y     = repeat y
continueWith (x:xs) y = x : (continueWith xs y)
```

Now, I don't understand the behavior of GHCi:

```
GHCi> let x = continueWith [1, 2] 3
x :: [Integer]
GHCi> :sp x
x = _
GHCi> take 3 x
[1,2,3]
it :: [Integer]
GHCi> :sp x
```

The last `sprint` doesn't terminate, but I expected the thunk returned by [`repeat`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-List.html#repeat) to be only evaluated up to the first cons:

```
...
GHCi> take 3 x
[1,2,3]
it :: [Integer]
GHCi> :sp x
x = 1 : 2 : 3 : _      <= This is not happening
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "problem" is that `repeat y` refers to itself,

```
repeat y = let ys = y:ys in ys
```

so once the first cons cell is evaluated, `repeat y` is completely evaluated. In ASCII art:

```
  (:) <-
 /  \  |
y    \_|
```

`:sp` prints as far as the thing is already evaluated ...